# mbstowcs from apache not getting executed

Tags: php, apache, perl, terminal

I am calling a perl script from one php page. This perl script calls some other scripts inturn and a C binary file. The C binary uses **mbstowcs** function inside. This is not getting executed correctly.

But the same thing If I call from terminal(the perl script) everything works fine.
I have given proper permissions to all the files before executing(Even gave 777 permission).
Is apache uses some other terminal session/ something else to run the scripts.
I am using ubuntu 14.04 and apache webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Without given any further information, I suspect you may have run across the following situation:

[Use of non standard mbstowcs feature](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-c-dev/200210.mbox/%3C20021023212240.14756.qmail@nagoya.betaversion.org%3E)

This information is dated I realize but it's all I can offer at this time unless you can provide some more information like an error message from your Apache log file.
Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: Apache log doesn't give any info.
so for using mbstowcs from apache environment, should i compile the c code i a different way?